# Parameter shall accept blank and when there's nothing mention in the parameter it should display all data

Tags: sql, t-sql

ssrs report parameter (xyz) shall accept blank (I have set the parameter properties to allow blanks) and when there's nothing mention in the parameter it should display all data. Example the report has 4 parameters including the parameter xyz that I created.

It's filtering the data when given the value. I also want the report to pull the data when the parameter is mentioned blank. I mean the entering the value of parameter xyz should not be mandatory.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
WHERE (@xyz = '' or table.field = @xyz)
AND ....
```